# How to pass multiple(2 or many) variables through behaviour subject in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

I am new to rxjs. In my application i have encountered a situation of passing username and password values from one component to another(In angular). Would you please help me passing these variables from one component to another component through behaviour subject with a neat basic example.
I have a class which stores the userdetails
UserInformation.ts as follows

```
export class UserInformation {
    username: string;
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

I have a service as follows.
User-information.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserInformation } from '../UserInformation';
@Injectable()
export class UserInformationService {
  userData:UserInformation;
  variable:string='ServiceVariable';
  constructor() {
    this.userData = new UserInformation(); 
   }
  getUserData()
  {
    return this.userData;
  }
  setUserData(userData:UserInformation)
  {
    this.userData.username=userData.username;
    console.log(this.userData.officeLocation);
  }
}
```

In my FirstComponent.ts I have the following code.This getVALuesFromForm method is used to get the username from the form.

```
getValuesFromForm()
   {
     this.enteredUser.username = this.loginform.get('Username').value;
     console.log(this.enteredUser.username);
     this.service.setUserData(this.enteredUser);     
   }
```

In my secondComponent.ts I have the following code.

```
import { Component, OnInit , Input , Output  } from '@angular/core';
import { UserInformation } from '../UserInformation';
import  { UserInformationService }   from '../services/user-information.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-bar-component',
  templateUrl: './nav-bar-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-bar-component.component.css'],
  providers:[UserInformationService]
})
@Injectable()
export class NavBarComponentComponent implements OnInit {
   userInfo:UserInformation;    
  constructor(public service:UserInformationService) {
    this.userInfo=service.getUserData();
    console.log(service.userData.username);
    console.log(this.userInfo.username);
   }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Now my question is how do we pass these variables from First Component to Second Component with the help of Behaviour Subject in Rxjs

Comment: Are you getting an error when you are calling setUserData in your 1st component?

Comment: The problem is that, both your components are getting separate instances of your service. You are setting value in instance 1 and getting value from instance 2

Answer (score 5):

Have an interface with properties as below,

```
export interface School {
    teacher: Teacher;
    student?: Student;
}

private emitter = new Subject<School>();

this.emitter.next({ student: ramStudent, teacher: Anieteacher});
```

Comment: This part It is fine. Now let us take a sample code .I will add some sample code so that I will get some clarity.

Comment: Aravind If you dont mind would you please look into the code and tell me how should I proceed.

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: No I dont have. I cant be available

Comment: I dont understand can you elaborate

Comment: In my FirstComponent.ts I am getting value from a form and I am calling setdata method in userService to set this form value to Userservice.ts variable.And now i am trying to get the data from the UserService.ts to SecondComponent.ts. But I am not able to get it.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need RxJS for your use case at all?

Read how to communicate between components in the angular docs:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

If you don't need to provide an initial value you could otherwise use just Subject.

One possibility is to achieve this trough a service:

```js
export interface ICredentials {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private credentials$ = new BehaviorSubject<ICredentials>({
        username: "initial username",
        password: "initial password"
    });

    constructor() {
    }

    public getCredentials(): Observable<ICredentials> {
        return this.credentials$;
    }

    public setCredentials(credentials: ICredentials) {
        this.credentials$.next(credentials);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'dog',
    template: '<div>Bark: Wuff Wuff {{credentials | json}}</div>'
})
export class DogComponent implements OnDestroy {
    private credentials: ICredentials;
    private credentialsSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.credentialsSubscription = this.userService.getCredentials().subscribe(credentials => this.credentials = credentials);
    }

    public ngOnDestroy() {
        this.credentialsSubscription && this.credentialsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'user',
    template: '<div>The User ...</div>'
})
export class UserComponent {
    private credentials: ICredentials = {
        username: "my users username",
        password: "my users password"
    };

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    }

    public shoutCredentials() {
        this.userService.setCredentials(this.credentials);
    }
}
```

Alternative you could communicate with the component like this:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'information-message',
    template: '<div>My message</div>'
})
export class InformationMessageComponent {
    @Output() public message: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
    private myMessage = "Hello World";

    constructor() {}

    public emitMessage() {
        this.message.emit(this.myMessage);
    }
}



@Component({
    selector: 'user',
    template: '<div>Did get message: {{theMessage}}</div> <information-message (message)="onMessage($event)"></information-message>'
})
export class InformationMessageComponent {
    public theMessage: string;

    constructor() {}

    public onMessage(message: string) {
        this.theMessage = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: this would be much easier, if you could explain what you try to achieve. Like an user story.

Comment: The code which you have suggested using observables is returning a null value when i am trying to print it.

Comment: I did edit the code, try again, so it is more clear what happens

Comment: Wuld you please execute in plunker and give me the link. I have tried it for so much time but still I am getting null values.

Answer (score 1):

In you component 1, you can do something like this:

```
export class FirstComponent
{
    username:string = "Some Name";
    age:number = "Some Age";
    obs = new Rx.BehaviourSubject();
    obs.next({username: this.username, age: this.age});
}
```

In your component 2, you can do this:

```
export class SecondComponent
{
    constructor(private fc: FirstComponent)
    secondComponentUsername:string;
    secondComponentAge:number;
    subscription = this.fc.obs().subscribe((response) => {
         this.secondComponentUsername = response.username;
         this.secondComponentAge = response.age;
    })
}
```

Comment: This is the very basic of what you have to do. Let me know if you need explanation :)

Comment: Vinod what is response here??

Comment: The response will be {username: this.username, age: this.age}

Comment: The first method inside your subscribe is what is called when you do obs.next()

Comment: And by seeing many posts I have observed that this passsing of variables they are doing through a service. I am also doing the same but I am able to set the values from First Component to service and I am displaying it in console for confirmation. Now when I am calling getDAta in other Component It is showing that the service variables are undefined.

Comment: In your first component, whenever your username and age changes, if you want to emit those new values to the second component, you can call the next method again

Comment: Ok can you put the entire code here? Component 1, service and Component 2

Comment: Yes I have to call in secondComponent again but I dont want that to happen I am using service in order to record data from First Component. Now when I subscribe from Second Component It is not giving the values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160255/discussion-between-roopteja-and-vinod-bhavnani).

Comment: I am on my office network, Chat access is restricted :) Sorry.You can paste your code in your question, and I will tell what you are doing wrong.